# Memory management - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, memory-management

I'm using Json framework in my project.

I parse the Json response as follow,

```
- (void)parseResponse:(NSData*)responseData
{
    NSMutableString *responseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *responseDic = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *responseDataString = [responseDic objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"JSON_RESPONSE_DICTIONARY_KEY", nil)];

    [responseString release];
}
```

So, is it correct if I call release on  **responseString** as I had done ??

**Edited**

I did as follow,

```
NSMutableString *responseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *responseDic = [responseString JSONValue]; 
NSString *responseDataString = [responseDic objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"JSON_RESPONSE_DICTIONARY_KEY", nil)];
NSDictionary *responseDataDic = [responseDataString JSONValue];
[responseString release];
```

I think now I'm safe.

Comment: not only correct, but necessary

Comment: Also, the order of the statements is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

> if you create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”. you must release that objects.

Comment: Yes. My problem was whether it will effect to the **responseDic** instance. So I edited my method. (I edited my question by adding it.)

Comment: responseDic is autorelease object. [responseString release]; will not effect responseDic.